# flutter_local_notifications, How to Choose a notification sound from system sounds?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, notifications, alarm

I am using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) plugin in my Flutter app and I need to change the sound of the notification channel from sounds in my device notification sounds list?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.